# Number of elements in a group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

The group $G$ consists of the binary strings of length $5$ under addition $\mod
2$ in each component. (It is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_2)^5$, the direct product of $5$ copies of $\mathbb Z_2$.)

I know the number of elements in $G$
 are $32$ but how do I find it??

Comment: Are you asking how do you find the number of elements of $C$?

Comment: This counting problem has nothing to do with groups by the way.

Comment: What has $\;C\;$ to do with the question *at all* ?

Comment: I guess you means that $C = <\{00000, 11001, 01110, 10111\}>$, the group generated by these elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Each string is of the form _ _ _ _ _, where each of the $5$ blanks can be either $1$ or $0$.  There are $2$ possibilities for the first blank, $2$ for the second, and so forth.  Hence, there are $2^5$ possible binary strings.

Edit: I'm not sure I have actually answered your question.  If you could elaborate on "How do I find it?", then I'll edit what I have here.

Comment: I have included the whole question I just want to know how to find the number of elements in a group